# Require two figures on consecutive pages to be horizontally aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, floats

How can I require two (large, near page-size) figures (on separate though consecutive/facing pages) to be horizontally aligned? I've tried `\begin{figure}[t]` but LaTeX ignores me. If they simply are at the top of the page.

Comment: If the figures are near page size and there is no other text on those pages anyway, do not use a figure environment. just use `\includegraphics{}` maybe inside a `center` environment if you have to. Then you can control the placement precisely with e.g. `\vspace*{length-value}`. If you need a captio use the `\captionof{figure}{pic description}` command from the `capt-of` or `caption` package

Comment: If you copypasta that response into an answer, I'll tick it!

Comment: @MartinH - With your method, you'll also need to provide instructions such as `\clearpage` to ensure that the graphs start at the top of a new page, right?

Comment: I did say that the figures were "large" so `\clearpage` isn't required, I don't think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, LaTeX's standard document classes will center a float that occupies a page by itself vertically; providing a location specifier such as `[t]` won't override this. If you want to the two floats to be top-aligned, you could issue the following commands:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0\p@} 
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
\makeatletter
```

If you want them to be bottom-aligned, just switch the arguments of the two `\setlength` instructions.

Comment: And also you can use a nonstretchable, nonzero unit for `\@fptop` to keep the tops of the figures at the same vertical positions (without losing a sense of balance in the page).

Comment: @Hugh - Thanks. You had indicated, three years ago, that the figures were "near page-size". As such, setting `\@fptop` to a (nontrivial) positive length might risk pushing one or both figures down so much as to make their bottom edge protrude into the page margin. That's why I had suggested setting `\setlength{\@fptop}{0\p@}`. Naturally, if the figures are not nearly as tall as the text block, then choosing `0pt` as the length for the top offset may be too cautious.